# Swift optionals returning nil after assigning it with a value

Tags: swift, option-type

I don't have much swift experience so your patience is appreciated. In the swift playground I have the following code:

```
import Foundation

class Test1 {
    var fav: Int?
    var test: FavouriteAd?

    func a() -> Int? {
        self.fav = 3
        self.test?.fav_id = 1212
        print("fav_id:",self.test?.fav_id)
        return self.fav
    }

    func add() -> Int? {
        self.fav! = self.fav! + 2
        return self.fav
    }
}

class FavouriteAd {
    var fav_id: Int?
    var user: Int?
    var fav_type: String?
    init?() {

    }
}


var z = Test1()
z.a()
print(z.add())

var z1 = Test1()
print(z.a())
```

Running the code results in:

```
fav_id: nil
Optional(5)
fav_id: nil
Optional(3)
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the `fav_id` printed out as `nil`? By defining `self.test?.fav_id = 1212`, does that not make it `1212`?
2. What do I need to do so that `1212` is associated with the object's `fav_id`? I thought by unwrapping it with `self.test?.fav_id!` will make a difference but it didn't.  I'm obviously lacking in the swift fundamentals, if someone can explain it that will be great. Thank you.

Comment: `test` is still nil so there's nothing to assign the value to.

Comment: You are using optional chaining therefore when assigning a new value it fails silently. `self.test?.fav_id = 1212` this mean if test is `nil` just skip

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys

Comment: You are welcome. just add `self.test = FavouriteAd()` the line before

Comment: Not related to your question but do you really need to declare your properties as optionals?  For the integers you can initialize them with `.zero` and regarding the  `FavouriteAd` type you should provide a proper initializer. Btw when coding in Swift most of times a structure is preferred over a class and it will give you the proper initializers for free. You would just need to declare your methods as mutating.